# The selnolig package: switching between English and German

Tags: ligatures, selnolig

Is it possible to load the ligature rules for English and German within the document, rather than by package options?   This would be useful for documents containing both languages. (It is possible to load both, but this has the unfortunate effect of breaking the fl-ligature in ‘briefly’, and probably others too.)

Comment: It would probably be more fun to explore this issue if we didn't have to construct a test file. (This is approximately reason #4 why it is almost always better to include a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) in your questions.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now, I'm afraid, it isn't possible to switch back and forth between language options in the `selnolig` package. Something to add in the medium to long term, for sure.

Congrats :-) on discovering a new language conflict case, which arises from the rule `\nolig{briefl}{brief|l}`. The rule is meant to catch German words such as "brieflich". However, it also catches the English language word "briefly". Until the next version of `selnolig` is released, please add the rule

```
\keeplig{briefly}
```

to the preamble, immediately after loading the `selnolig` package.

Fortunately, there aren't all that many language overlap conflicts with this package -- at least not that I'm aware of. Before you pointed out "briefly", I was aware of only three overlap cases: "Mohnflesserl" (a poppy seed pastry), "fünffingrig" (five-fingered), and "Zwölffingerdarm" (duodenum). Moreover, the second and third case arise only if the package's `broadf` option is enabled.